# Remove spacing between two paragraphs when displaying WYSIWIGS with ckeditor 4 in Angular

Tags: angular, css, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

I'm using Angular 4 with ckeditor 4.x for WYSIWYG.

So when I'm displaying the code from database, the view is not the same in ckeditor, even if there's no style applying with paragraph.

I've tryed to reduce the `line-height` with CSS but no-way, it's the same result.

I removed the `margin` between lines but the same matters.

This is the code of the CSS where I've tryed to solve the problem:

```css
p, p + p{
    color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
    display:block;
    font-family:sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:normal;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    -webkit-margin-after:0px;
    -webkit-margin-before:0px;
    -webkit-margin-end:0px;
    -webkit-margin-start:0px;
}
```

```html
<p>This one line</p> 
<p>this is the second lines</p> 
<p>And another one</p> 
<p>And a last lines</p>
```

This is the view:

[image]

Here's the computed code in dev tools

[image]

Comment: What is the computed result in the dev tools? It's possible you need to be more specific with your selector

Comment: Are there any empty `p` elements being generated? Or `br` elements

Comment: I had the computed code in the post

Comment: That's the computed CSS. I'm wondering what the HTML looks like? Maybe there's an extra `p` or `br` element causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by removing the `white-space:pre-wrap;`. I Don't kwon why it's add a space between lines.

Answer (score 0):

try this : remove height:

```
p{
    color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
    display:block;
    font-family:sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:13px;

    line-height:1.2;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap:break-word;
margin-bottom:10px

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who encounter this problem it is usually the result of the fact that your global styles 'bleed' into the ckeditor instance.

So if you have a global style set for `<p>` that has a margin-bottom (which by default bootstrap sets) then you need to remove it at the global level:

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

You cannot set this style on the component-level CSS because that will only effect the html of your component and not the html inside ckeditor itself.